# How to set encoding in .getJSON jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, character-encoding

In my web app, I submit some form fields with jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method. I am having some problems with the encoding. The character-set of my app is `charset=ISO-8859-1`, but I think these fields are submitted with `UTF-8`.

How I can set encoding used in `$.getJSON` calls?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098683/95735) answer it's illegal to specify charset for `application/json`.

Comment: **ILLEGAL?** I hope I don't get arrested for trying...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think that you'll probably have to use [`$.ajax()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) if you want to change the encoding, see the `contentType` param below (the `success` and `error` callbacks assume you have `<div id="success"></div>` and `<div id="error"></div>` in the html):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomePage.aspx/GetSomeObjects",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{id: '" + someId + "'}",
    success: function(json) {
        $("#success").html("json.length=" + json.length);
        itemAddCallback(json);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#error").html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

I actually just had to do this about an hour ago, what a coincidence!

Comment: I just figured out that you overriding XMLHttpRequest host object inside error method. Its just a matter of good coding practice not to confuse other developers ;) I would suggest rename it to something else ;)

Comment: Much better :) (in fact usually I name it the same as u now :>)

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098683/95735) answer it's illegal to specify charset for `application/json`.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to use `$.getJSON()` you can add the following before the call :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

You can use the charset you want instead of `utf-8`.

The options are explained [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#toptions).

`contentType :` When sending data to the server, use this `content-type`. Default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is fine for most cases.

`scriptCharset :` Only for requests with `jsonp` or `script` dataType and GET type. Forces the request to be interpreted as a certain charset. Only needed for charset differences between the remote and local content.

You may need one or both ...

Comment: hi Pat, I'm having same problem of setting content type with getJSON method. I used $.ajaxSetup just before calling getJSON, but no change occurs, the "nordic" characters becomes junk characters in my DB. could you pls tell me the exact order of calling mathods? thnx

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13098683/95735) answer it's illegal to specify charset for `application/json`.

Comment: I had a similar issue with post and was using $.ajax(...) call instead of $.post(...) because I didn't have a way to change the content type.  This allows me to use the abbreviated $.post notation to match the $.get that I am using. I believe this should be the accepted answer because it works and allows the use of $.getJSON().

Answer (score 5):

You need to analyze the JSON calls using Wireshark, so you will see if you include the charset in the formation of the JSON page or not, for example:

- If the page is simple if text / html

```
0000  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31  20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d   HTTP/1.1  200 OK.
0010  0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74  2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74   .Content -Type: t
0020  65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c  0d 0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d   ext/html ..Cache-
0030  43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a  20 6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68   Control:  no-cach
```

- If the page is of the type including custom JSON with MIME "charset = ISO-8859-1"

```
0000  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31  20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d   HTTP/1.1  200 OK.
0010  0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43  6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20   .Cache-C ontrol: 
0020  6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65  0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e   no-cache ..Conten
0030  74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20  74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d   t-Type:  text/htm
0040  6c 3b 20 63 68 61 72 73  65 74 3d 49 53 4f 2d 38   l; chars et=ISO-8
0050  38 35 39 2d 31 0d 0a 43  6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f   859-1..C onnectio
```

Why is that? because we can not put on the page of JSON a goal like this:

In my case I use the manufacturer Connect Me 9210 Digi:

- I had to use a flag to indicate that one would use non-standard MIME:
                   p-> theCgiPtr-> = fDataType eRpDataTypeOther;
- It added the new MIME in the variable:
                   strcpy (p-> theCgiPtr-> fOtherMimeType, "text / html;
  charset = ISO-8859-1 ");

**It worked for me** without having to convert the data passed by JSON for UTF-8 and then redo the conversion on the page ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURI()` in client JS and use `URLDecoder.decode()` in server Java side works.

---

Example:

- **Javascript**:

  ```
  $.getJSON(
      url,
      {
          "user": encodeURI(JSON.stringify(user))
      },
      onSuccess
  );
  ```
- **Java**:

  `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(params.user, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to regain the utf-8 characters

```
function decode_utf8(s) { 
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s)); 
}
```

Example:
    var new_Str=decode_utf8(str);

Answer (score 0):

f you want to use $.getJSON() you can add the following before the call :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Comment: Excuse me but, how is your answer different from @Pat 's **11 years** before yours?