# Is there a ADO.NET Data Services jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, wcf-data-services

ADO.NET Data Services looks very cool, and I would love to use it with a jQuery backed ajax website.

Do any of you great people here on StackOverflow know of a jQuery plugin that will ease the CRUD operations against an ADO.NET Data Service?

Regards, Egil.

**UPDATE**: It turns out that the [ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 (currently in preview 4)](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24645) has very nice support for ADO.NET Data Services, and it looks like it works pretty well with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 (currently in preview 4)](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24645) has very nice support for ADO.NET Data Services, and it looks like it works pretty well with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The out of the box getJSON method of jQuery works just fine with ADO.NET Data Services. Just remember to set the content type correct as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery/27023#27023)