# jQuery: Set encoding for json response to utf8

Tags: jquery, encoding, utf-8

I'm getting my response for jQuery in json. The logic works fine, but I can't get him to proper encode the data (like üäö).

I've searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery) question on SO, which suggested to change the `getJSON` to a normal AJAX call. I've done that, and added the `setContentType` option, but still, I'm getting weird signs, as soon as an äüö appears.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

```
$(function() {
    $("#cnAntragsteller").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/api",
                dataType: "jsonp", 
                data: {
                    search: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.persons, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.cn + " (PN: " + item.imPersonalNumber + ")",
                            value: item.cn,
                            pn: item.imPersonalNumber,
                            cn: item.cn,
                            cc: item.imCostCenter,
                            jb: item.imJobTitle,
                            jbd: item.imJobTitleDescription
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },

        minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#pnAntragsteller").val(ui.item.pn);
            $("#jbAntragsteller").val(ui.item.jb);
            $("#jbdAntragsteller").val(ui.item.jbd);
            $("#ouKostenstelle").val(ui.item.cc);


            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/api",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    pn: ui.item.pn
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#cnLeiter").val(data.cn);
                }
            });
            }
        })
})
```

Response Headers (first Header doesn't display data, it just redirects to the output):

```
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 22 May 2012 06:13:41 GMT
Location:http://localhost/api/redirection
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Length:177
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 22 May 2012 06:13:41 GMT
Expires:0
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Note: These are only the response headers, do the request headers also contain important information?

Comment: Have you made sure that the server return data in UTF-8?

Comment: Well, I tought of that, but since it's only the json output, and no html, I can't add a meta tag. Output is generated by some JSP page.

Comment: Can you try using Web Inspector (Chrome/Safari) or Firebug to look at the output? Check the header and the data. Also make sure the OutputStream is writing in UTF-8.

Comment: @nhahtdh Added headers in question. What do you mean with OutputStream?

Comment: If the Writer, wrapping the OutputStream, does not write in UTF-8 encoding, then the data is messed up right from server.

Comment: @nhahtdh If I call the api page directly in the browser, I don't have any problems, all special chars are display correctly.

Comment: Have you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454053/characters-with-jquery-json

Comment: @nhahtdh Well, accepted answer is a solution for PHP. Other answer took the same approach, as I did (getJSON to ajax call with contentType).

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok, I've got the solution for the response (see answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it seems like you already solved the problem, it might be good to point out two things:

1. jQuery's `getJSON` is using UTF-8 by default. What the accepted
   answer on the page you gave meant was that if you want some encoding
   other than UTF-8, you can use `$.ajax()`. Actually, as another
   answer on that page said, even if you use `getJSON`, you can still
   use `$.ajaxSetup` to set encoding.
2. You might want to change your JSP headers contentType to `'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, because that's what your jQuery side is expecting for. It's always good to make things consistent.

Comment: Thank you for the additional informations. I'll update it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it trough adding the JSP headers (I don't know JSP, so it took me some googling). Adding this on the page import tag solved the issue:

```
<%@ page import="someEngine"  contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't of much help. I think you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh Hey, thanks for the help anyway, your approach was right. You have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.