# Arabic texts in php/mysql sometimes appear “???” and sometime appear "ÙØ¤ØªØ§" after select/insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have an ongoing project where I need to fetch Arabic texts from mysql table and also insert/update them time to time. I have my database collation in "utf8_general_ci".

At first I found question marks "???" upon fetching some of the arabic data. Then I have executed "SET CHARACTER SET utf8". The question mark problem of that particular problem was solved, but then other arabic data started showing gibberish "ÙØ¤ØªØ§". In the project I also need to fetch some data from csv containing arabic texts.

Here is the json data I found before and after the charset execution:

```
[{
  "id": 148,
  "domain": 0,
  "group_name": "ATX ??????????",
  "score": 0,
  "player_name": "لاعب واحد",
  "created_at": "2015-10-26 13:01:23"
},
{
  "id": 148,
  "domain": 0,
  "group_name": "???? ???????",
  "score": 1,
  "player_name": "اثنين من لاعب",
  "created_at": "2015-10-26 12:59:57"
}]

// ---------------------------------------
// After executing "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"
// ---------------------------------------  


[{
  "id": 148,
  "domain": 0,
  "group_name": "ATX توكوروزاوا",
  "score": 0,
  "player_name": "Ù…Ø¤ØªØ§",
  "created_at": "2015-10-26 13:01:23"
},
{
  "user_id": 148,
  "domain": 0,
  "group_name": "لندن دينيموز",
  "score": 1,
  "player_name": "ÙƒØ§Ø¨ÙˆØ§",
  "created_at": "2015-10-26 12:59:57"
}]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here? I'm trying to fix this but can't find any solution.

Comment: try utf8_encode on the value again i.e. on player_name

Comment: tried. it shows another gibberish form "Ã™Â„Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â¹Ã˜Â¨"  :/

Comment: here surely this will fix it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696466/jquery-set-encoding-for-json-response-to-utf8

Comment: You can also read this https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/93363/inserting-arabic-characters-into-mysql

Answer (score 2):

`Ù…Ø¤ØªØ§` is Mojibake for `مؤتا`:

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

`Ã™Â„Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â¹Ã˜Â¨` may be a "double encoding" -- avoid that path.

`"ATX ??????????"` --

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

See also [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: See also this for troubleshooting Mojibake, Double-encoding, question marks, etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have text with 2 different character encodings in your database, utf8 and, I'm guessing, latin1. You'll have to decide on which to use definitely (I suggest utf8) and update the text in the other encoding to match.

Try something like this to test for the correct encoding:

```
SELECT group_name, CONVERT(player_name USING utf8) FROM your_table;
```

If the output is correct, you can then correct the data permanently with:

```
UPDATE your_table SET player_name = CONVERT(player_name USING utf8);
```

*See [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html_)*