# MySQL SELECT on Arabic Word returns 0 results on PHP but does on SQLBuddy/phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, arabic-support

**Problem**

I am getting 0 results when searching for an Arabic word in a MySQL database using the `SELECT` query with PHP.

However, the same exact query yields results in alternative clients, namely SQLBuddy and the likes. Everything is encoded in UTF-8.

**Code**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "hans_wehr_client";
    // i know my security is a joke :)
    $password = "hans_wehr"; 
    $database = "hans_wehr";
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
    if ($conn == TRUE){
        $search = $_GET["search"];
        $encoded_search = utf8_encode($search);
        echo $encoded_search."<br>";
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE ARABIC LIKE '$search'";
        echo $sql."<br>";
        mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
                echo $row["ARABIC"]. " - Meaning: " . $row["ENGLISH1"]. " " . $row["ENGLISH2"]. "<br>";
            }
        }else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }

?>
```

Before the mods get the pitchforks, I have to clear up my troubleshooting logic.

1. **Encoding.** I set the page encoding to `utf-8` using `header('Content-Type:
   text/html; charset=utf-8');` and ran the queries `mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");` and `mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');`, this cleared up the `???????` and `ÙØ¤ØªØ§`
   rendered instead of Arabic words issue. That is kind of a different
   issue. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513812/mysqli-non-english-characters?lq=1) and [Source2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360108/arabic-texts-in-php-mysql-sometimes-appear-and-sometime-appear-%C3%99%C3%98%C2%A4%C3%98%C2%AA%C3%98-a)
2. **Database Charset.** My database and columns are set to UTF-8.
3. **Other clients work.** SQLBuddy/MySQL native client/ PHPMyAdmin appear to be working because running the same exact query yields result. Therefore I appear to be on the same bloody boat with [him.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513812/mysqli-non-english-characters?lq=1) The query `SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE ARABIC LIKE 'آخَر، أُخرى'` returns a result on SQLbuddy but nada on PHP.

**Possible solution:**

Running the query `SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE ARABIC LIKE 'آخَر، أُخرى'` yields me a result.

However running the query with a **UTF-8** encoded version of the Arabic word returns 0 results. `SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE ARABIC LIKE '&#1570;&#1582;&#1614;&#1585;&#1548; &#1571;&#1615;&#1582;&#1585;&#1609;'` I think this simulates PHP.

The **UTF-8** Arabic word version is obtained by decoding the automatically URL encoded $[_GET] parameter i.e `%26%231570%3B%26%231582%3B%26%231614%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231548%3B+%26%231571%3B%26%231615%3B%26%231582%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231609%3B`

Could it be that the MySQLi actually queries the `UTF-8 version` instead of the actual Arabic word? Therefore finding no match since they are different?

If so how can I explicitly tell PHP not to **URL encode** my search term and therefore pass it as it is?

Since according to my tinfoil theory, `http://localhost/hans_wehr/search_ar.php?search=آخَر، أُخرى` would work but `http://localhost/hans_wehr/search_ar.php?search=%26%231570%3B%26%231582%3B%26%231614%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231548%3B+%26%231571%3B%26%231615%3B%26%231582%3B%26%231585%3B%26%231609%3B`

Inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use  html_entity_decode():

Use html_entity_decode() on your $_GET["search"] value

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "hans_wehr_client";
// i know my security is a joke :)
$password = "hans_wehr"; 
$database = "hans_wehr";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn == TRUE){
    $search = $_GET["search"];
    $encoded_search =html_entity_decode($search, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    echo $encoded_search."<br>";
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE ARABIC LIKE '$encoded_search'";
    echo $sql."<br>";
    mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($conn,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo $row["ARABIC"]. " - Meaning: " . $row["ENGLISH1"]. " " . $row["ENGLISH2"]. "<br>";
        }
    }else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Too bad I don't have 15 reputation to vote you up, you have the correct answer my friend.