# How to get Arabic value coming from Java Object encoded properly in Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, post, model-view-controller

In MVC, I am trying to make Ajax call in the front end to retrieve an object that has a String in the Arabic language. Everything works fine, but the Arabic String value comes as question marks (?????????). How to solve this issue?

Ajax call:

```
function getSectorById(sectorId){
        
        var sector=null;
        $.ajax({  
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              url: contextPath + "/secure/services/getSectorById/"+sectorId,
              contentType: contentTypeJSON,
              success: function(data) {
                  sector=JSON.parse(data);  
                  alert(sector.nameAr);
              },
             error: function(response){
                 alert(response);
             }
                                    
        });
        
        return sector;
    }
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSectorById/{sectorId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getSectorById(ModelAndView mav, @PathVariable BigDecimal sectorId) {
        Sector sector = getSector(sectorId);
        
        System.out.println(sector.getNameAr());
        
        CustomSector sec = new CustomSector(sector.getNameEn(), sector.getNameAr());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(sec);
        
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        return jsonString ;
    }
```

I tried to do this:

```
contentType: "contentTypeJSON; charset=UTF-8",
```

But I keep getting the value sector.nameAr as:

```
???? ????? ????? ?????????
```

How can I get the Arabic value correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In which format you are getting the response data? follow these steps first alert the data and see how the data is coming if data is JSON Format you can directly access its data.Namear.

Comment: String format like this:  {nameEn:SectorName, nameAr: ??????????}

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198532/jquery-ajax-call-messes-up-character-encoding)

```
 contentType: "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-15",
```

Comment: I don't have the response variable in java. So I am not sure where to place this.

Comment: I guess in this case use it as a header contentType: "contentTypeJSON; charset=ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Yeah, I did that but it's not working. Still getting question marks (???????????????)

Comment: can you check what is the `content-encoding` in the response headers