# How to ensure variables submitted in UTF8 using jquery $.post

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have been struggling with this for three days now and this is what i have got and i cannot understand why i am seeing this behavior.

my problem is that i have a MySql spanish db with char set and collation defined as utf8_general_ci. when i query the data base in delete.php like this `"DELETE FROM countryNames WHERE country = '$name'"`

the specified row doesnot get deleted. i am setting the variable $name in delete.php through a post variable `$name=$_post['data']` .  mostly $name gets the value in spanish characters e.g español, México etc. the delete.php file gets called from main.php.if i send a post message from main.php `$.post("delete.php", {data:filename});` , the query doesnot deletes the entry (although the 'filename' string is in utf8) but if i create a form and then post my data variable in main.php, the query works!! the big question to me is why do i have to submit a form for the query to work? what im seeing is my database rejects the value if it comes from a jquery post call but accepts it when its from a submitted form. (i make no code change for the query to work. just post the value by submiting the form)

Comment: do a `var_dump` of the post variable and see what you get in both instances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set encoding in .getJSON JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery)

Comment: @ Neal : in both the cases it says string(37) or string(34) etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys this was a Mac problem!! i just tested it on windows as my server and now everything works fine. So beware when u r using Mac as a server with MySql having UTF8 as charset and collation. I guess the Mac stores the folder and file name in some different encoding and not UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to see what charset ìs used for requests, install something like Firebug and check the 'Content-Type' header of your request/response. It will look something like 'application/json; charset=...'. This should be `charset=utf-8` in your case.

My guess why it worked when posting a form is probably because of [x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) - non-alphanumeric characters are additionally encoded on the client side and again decoded on the server, that's the difference to posting the data directly.

This means that somewhere there is a wrong encoding at work. PHP treats your strings agnostic to its encoding by default, so I would tend to rule it out as the source of the error. `jQuery.post` also uses UTF-8 by default... so my suspect is the `filename` variable. Are you sure it is in UTF-8? Where and how do you retrieve it?

You should probably also ensure that the actual HTML page is also sent as UTF-8 and not, let's say iso-8859-1. Have a look at this [article](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets) for a thorough explanation on how to get it right.

Comment: thanks for the reply...the filename variable comes from a folder on my hard drive which i read thru php script. the folder names are the country names in spanish text.

Comment: On Windows, Linux, Mac? Because NTFS on Windows for example uses UTF-16 for its file names, so this could already be your problem...

Comment: im on mac..additionally if make the "filename" equal to español by myself in the code, instead of reading it from the disk. it works :S...so in conclusion the filename is not in utf-8! but i check the encoding (mb_detect_encoding() )before and after the post call and it gives me UTF-8 :S

Comment: Hmm, have not much experience with Macs... but they should use the platform default encoding similar to Linux. You could use `iconv` to enforce UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You answer might be here: [How to set encoding in .getJSON JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery)

As it says there, use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` and you can set encoding.

OR, as it says in the 2nd answer use `$.ajaxSetup` to set the encoding accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use .serialize() ! I think it will work. More info: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/