# getJSON only responds to plaintext and will not work otherwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using $getJSON to pull down a JSON string from a link (e.g. /login?user=foo&pass=bar). When I plug this link straight into the browser I get a "File Download" prompt ("which is a: application/json"). getJSON does NOT work on that link.

However! When I open the file in the "file download" prompt in notepad and host that text onto my server as just plain text (.txt file) and call getJSON on THAT link (i.e /jsondata.txt), it works perfectly.

Keep in mind I don't have the ability to change anything on the back end.

Any idea what is going on here? Basically I can pull down the JSON file when I host it as plain text but not as it is returned by default.

**EDIT**
Here's my code...pretty straightforward:

```
  $.getJSON("http://EXTERNALHOSTNAME.com/WEBSERVICE.svc/login?username="+document.frmLogin.email.value+"&password="+document.frmLogin.password.value+"", function(data) {

alert("it worked!");
});
```

if I replace that line with a link to a dropbox .txt file, it works:

```
//$.getJSON("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/NUMBERS/login.txt", function(data) {
```

Comment: can you post your getJSON code?

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery/26681#26681)

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"? Could you provide the exact error? Is that link on the same domain or a different one (because I suspect the problem might be somewhere else)? Also, if you get a File Download the link could be with a 'content-disposition' header http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519. I do not know how $.getJson behaves in that case.

Comment: See the *edit* above

I'm not really sure what Error is thrown (how can I find out?). I just know that if I replace the link with a .txt file of the data contained it works fine. The real link by itself has no file extension but (when opened from the download prompt in notepad or wordpad) reveals the identical data.

Comment: PPvG, I tried that too (saw it elsewhere online). When I put the appropriate URL in and put "{}" next to the 'data:' element, it gets thrown into the AJAX error callback. I print the xhr.responseText in an alert window and it is empty.

Comment: @PPvG: I agree, win services are fussy when the content type header doesn't come across (as the service is reliant on that header to determine which content type to render). -- EDIT: Also, something to keep in mind: You're probably doing to need to access `data.d` for the _Real_ content, as MS likes to add another level hair-pulling to every equation.

Comment: It's throwing an error when I use the solution PPvG suggested. The string xhr.responseText is blank.

Comment: In which browser dose this error occur?

Comment: This happens in firefox. However, $.getJSON does not work in any of the browsers i'm using (i'm using mobile browesers).

Comment: Are you trying to request to a different domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call other domains (other than originating domain) from javascript. If `EXTERNALHOSTNAME` supports jsonp responses, you can solve your problem with ading `&callback=?` to your query. If not you can put a script on your server that will route that response, so that it appears as originating from your own domain. Other than that, if you can serve pages from `EXTERNALHOSTNAME` (which I doubt) you can serve an iframe from that domain that executes this ajax call (so that it doesn't violate same origin rule), and then smuggle that data to parent frame.