# Fetch Icecast song title without buffering audio

Tags: audio, streaming, shoutcast, icecast, internet-radio

I want to write a small JavaScript library that can fetch "now playing" data for Icecast streams. From what I [understand](http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html), I can do this by sending  a HTTP request to a radio stream as follows:

```
GET /radiotunes_bebop HTTP/1.1
Host: pub2.radiotunes.com
Icy-MetaData:1
```

The server will then answer with some reponse headers. One of them is the `icy-metaint` field that indicates the interval at which the metadata is inserted into the stream. The metadata will look something like this:

```
StreamTitle='Dexter Gordon - Jodi';StreamUrl='';
```

Although this gets me the information I need, it isn't very efficient if you don't need the audio itself. (This can be the case when the stream isn't playing.) Is there a way to fetch the stream title without buffering the audio? I know I can scrape HTML to get it, but that method has significant limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHOUTcast/Icecast metadata always comes after the first audio chunk.  There is no way to get in-stream metadata without having an audio chunk before it.

The good news is that this isn't as inefficient as you might think.  Most stations use 8KB metadata intervals.  Many use 16KB intervals.  I don't think I have ever seen a metadata interval greater than 32KB.  The server side will buffer the audio stream and flush this buffer as soon as you connect.  You will often receive metadata within the first or second response packet.

If it's helpful to you, I have a [free API available for fetching metadata from streams](http://audiopump.co/accounts/products/manage/api) that does exactly what you propose.  It connects to a stream, skips through the audio data, parses the metadata, and returns JSON.  It is accessible from within the browser.

### Request

```
$.getJSON('http://api.audiopump.co/metadata/getStreamMetadata', {
  url: 'http://cdn.audiopump.co/radioreddit/main_mp3_128k',
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

### Response

```
{
  "streamInfo": {
    "contentType": "audio/mpeg",
    "name": "Radio Reddit - Main",
    "genres": [
      "Indie",
      "Rock",
      "Talk"
    ],
    "websiteUrl": "http://radioreddit.com",
    "isPublic": true
  },
  "current": {
    "filename": "the_Nothingdoers_(evanowe)_Things_We_Should_Forget.mp3",
    "StreamTitle": "the Nothingdoers (/u/evanowe) - Things We Should Forget"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I ran into some trouble with non-ASCII characters in the API's responses: http://i.imgur.com/nfcpgIH.png http://i.imgur.com/TA46n36.png The é character is not being decoded correctly despite the presence of a `Content-Type` header indicating UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Pieter Thanks for the bug report.  The station name encoding issue is a bug, which I think is in the core of Node.js which is what my API server runs on.  https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8699  I'm working on confirming that, and hopefully a workaround.  The stream metadata itself though... the metadata is expected to be in UTF-8 already.  However, many encoders don't do this.  I am considering adding an option where you can specify your encoding.  Would this be helpful?  Do you know what encoding you're using?  And, do you have a stream I can reproduce this on?

Comment: I do `$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});` before I fire off my request as per [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023/217649), but I don't see anything in my request headers about UTF-8. You can reproduce the error using this stream: http://pub6.radiotunes.com/radiotunes_cafedeparis

Comment: @Pieter The API will always return UTF-8.  The issue is that the source stream itself is assumed to be in UTF-8, as that is what most encoders use.  (Unfortunately, a character encoding isn't really defined for metadata in SHOUTcast, so not all encoders use UTF-8.)  That is the stream I am testing with, but I haven't seen any accented characters since I was testing with it.  I will try again later today, and will add a parameter for the stream's metadata encoding.  I will get back to you.  Could you also send an e-mail to brad@audiopump.co so I could contact via e-mail?  Thanks.

Comment: For future reference: this method no longer works. I'm getting a 504 Gateway Time-out from an nginx server when I try to access the API. Ah well, it's a free service... it was fun while it lasted.

Comment: @Pieter I've been having some problems with the hosting of this API, but am working on getting in a permanent fix.  Sorry for the trouble that you are having!  Please e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

Since Icecast 2.4 the preferred way to get machine readable meta-data about the streams running through a server is status-json.xsl. This JSON API is default enabled on all installations. Since 2.4.1 it is by default an open API and sending an ACAO header of "*".

In case of old Icecast installations (2.3.x): they can be retrofitted with the JSON API (it would be enough for the administrator to copy status-json.xsl and xml2json.xslt from the **2.4.1** release to the web directory).

Comment: One major caveat: this doesn't work universally. Some of the biggest internet-only radio networks don't even support it yet (e.g. [Digitally Imported](http://pub2.di.fm/status-json.xsl) and [SomaFM](http://ice.somafm.com/status-json.xsl)). Hopefully this situation will improve in the future. In the meantime, I'm afraid that I'll have to stick with the crappier yet more reliable solution.

Comment: Sure, this is for when you are creating a web page for a specific stream. If you have to work with random streams, you're screwed. The ICY scraping won't work if the stream is Vorbis or OPUS, as there the metadata is in the Ogg container. Firefox has a JS metadata API, but thats vendor specific.