# How to display Now Playing in my website with Icecast2 and Liquidsoap

Tags: php, html, icecast, liquidsoap

I couldn't find any better answer to this online, even the document of liquidsoap isn't helpful. What I want to happen is to grab the current song title and artist being played in my streaming server(icecast). I found in some forum that they were able to do it but they didn't explain it how, here's the liquidsoap script that they used:

```
def apply_metadata(m) =
  title = m["title"]
  artist = m["artist"]
  album = m["album"]
  [("artist","#{artist}"),("title","#{album} - #{title}")]
end

centovacast.callback_autodj := fun(s) -> map_metadata(apply_metadata,s)
```

This script i believe is also for centova and autodj only. While I do not use those technology (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Icecast2, Liquisoap, PHP, HTML5/CSS), 
is this possible to do using the tools I'm currently using?

Answer (score 3):

I used to use websockets to get the metadata but I found it frustrating that it was always out of sync.

The only way to solve it is to have the metadata encoded into the stream so you receive it at the same time as the audio.

I did a bit of digging around to find out how the icecast servers do it and put together a service worker script which adds the necessary header to your request to obtain a stream including metadata and then extracts it for you.

The code is [here](https://github.com/cryptiksouls/icecast-shoutcast-metadata-grabber) and there is a simple demo [here](https://toohotradio.net/metadata.html)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps, anyway, I think that here, weserWEB, has already somehow said something similar.
If you're using Icecast version 2.4.4 you can consume the metadata from this endpoint: (if not, consider downloading that version)

```
http://<your-ipaddress-or-domain>:<port_number>/status-json.xsl
```

Just put that in any browser and you will get a JSON with the name of the song and title you are streaming, you have to configure properly your streaming client first, of course.
Then you can get the metadata from that endpoint without problems in your PHP. You can use CURL to get the JSON data, liquidsoap not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are dragging the source client into this.

A proper stream sent to an Icecast mountpoint will have metadata for currently playing audio.

This has been pointed out [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817214/fetch-icecast-song-title-without-buffering-audio/27127788#27127788). Icecast since 2.4.1 provides a proper JSON metadata export.

Querying JSON from within a website is very much a solved problem and considered an exercise for the inclined reader.

Comment: Ok I got the json file and I can parse it too now. The problem is it doesn't sync with the player: when the song changes, the title of the song does not change...

Comment: Yes, that's expected and a known limitation. Most players will buffer up data before starting to play. Also, the buffer might grow over time for multiple reasons. This means that while the server is already seeing the next song, the player might only get to it in anywhere from 5 to 60 seconds. Synchronized metadata you would only get by reading it from the stream, but there is no standardized way to do this in a browser. NB: There are quite a few software players that get this wrong even. They read metadata as it comes in, not where they are in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you grab this at icecast directly?

PHP:

```
function get_icecast_info($server_ip, $server_port, $admin_user, $admin_password) {
    $index = @file_get_contents("http://".$admin_user.":".$admin_password."@".$server_ip.":".$server_port."/admin/stats.xml");
    if($index) {
        $xml = new DOMDocument(); if(!$xml->loadXML($index)) return false; $arr = array(); $listItem = $xml->getElementsByTagName("source");
        foreach($listItem as $element) {
            if($element->childNodes->length) {
                foreach($element->childNodes as $i){ $arr[$element->getAttribute("mount")][$i->nodeName] = $i->nodeValue; }
            }
        }
        return $arr;
    } return false;
}
```

And this is the output (array):

```
$arr = get_icecast_info($ice_host, $ice_aport, $ice_user, $ice_pass);
```

Comment: Please note that the above answer is exactly about querying Icecast directly and doesn't require administrator level access.