# How can I change the charset incoming from Java servlet using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, character-encoding

I have this servlet at http://localhost.com.br:8080/servlet/apps.ctr.HTMLCtr?p1=getCtr. It returns a JSON by the way.

When I try to get data via JavaScript/jQuery the `ã` and `ç` characters turn into a black diamond with a question mark in the center: `�`

I thought there was something misconfigured in my server side, but if I try to reach it with my Chrome browser I get the data, such as:

```
"Liberação de Registro",
"Mar 28, 2016"
```

I thought this was related to the client side encoding, so I tried the options available at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#toptions:

```
var s = 'http://localhost.com.br:8080/servlet/apps.ctr.HTMLCtr?';
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
});

$.getJSON(s,function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

I tried changing the charset to ISO-8859-1 or even ISO-8859-15 and running the above code on Chrome's console, but nothing has changed.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: This is not a duplicated of [How to set encoding in .getJSON JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery) because that question is related to sending information to the servlet, my question is about getting the information from the servlet. Also, the solutions provided on that question on using `$.ajaxSetup` did not solve my issue.

EDIT2: The Response Header from Chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: max-stale=0
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Length: 224
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 16:58:26 GMT
```

Also posting the HTML (I'm excluding the `<body>` part):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="br.com.project1.usuario.Usuario"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CbrCpt</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/bootstrap-datepicker-1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/accounting.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.jqdock.min.js'></script>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/datepicker-pt-BR.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/moment-with-locales.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dataTables.responsive.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.maskedinput.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/cbrcpt.js'></script>
</html>
```

EDIT3: When opening the response on the Chrome console, the information has the correct characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set encoding in .getJSON JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery)

Comment: I would try to change the charset so your java code sends utf8 instead

Comment: `contentType` JQuery option is for encoding outgoing data. Try to use Chrome console to make sure, that your servlet responds with correct `Content-type` header

Comment: can you post your html code

Comment: I tried using response.setCharacterEncoding(); as mentioned by Endless, but both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 resulted on the same situation