# Passing Unicode string from Python dict to JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, unicode

I have a dict that contains some Unicode strings (among other objects). I'd like to save this dict as a JSON file, and then display the content of this via AJAX.

If `final_res` is the dict, I usually do this:

```
json.dumps(final_res, ensure_ascii=True)
```

In the result, I see strings like:

```
"l\\u00a0m\\u00fcdale"
```

I imagine these are unicode encoded characters. But when I try to display them in Javascript, these get printed with the slashes, instead of the encoded unicode letter.

Is there something I am doing wrong in Javascript for displaying these properly? Or should I do decode these into ASCII in Python, before outputting to JSON?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the discussion in the comments below with @spectra, I realized that `json.dumps` should not be outputting double slashes. When I parse this in the browser, this prints it as a literal single slash.

I am trying to figure out a way to fix this with the `json` module, not sure why it's happening.

Comment: What do you use to send the result to the browser?

Comment: I see the string printed as `"l\\u00a0m\\u00fcdale"`

Comment: Why are you using `ensure_ascii=True`? And how are you parsing the JSON on the Javascript side? If you just display the raw JSON string, you'll of course get Unicode escapes in there, but if you actually parse and use the JSON, the escapes should be processed into Unicode by the parser.

Comment: @user1496984> I got that. What I am asking is how you send the string to the browser. Are you using Django? Flask? Some custom code?

Comment: @user2357112 I parse it using `react-refetch`. I don't simply dump the result of the AJAX call, but I print out the relevant items of the original `final_res` dict, as in `final_refetch[0]['name']`, which still has the backslashes..

Comment: @spectras I store this JSON in a DB, served over Django. On the client-side, I pull this using `react-refetch`, which passes it as a `props` to my component. Within the component, I print it using the `<td>{v[0]['name']</td>` syntax..

Comment: Alright, I'm asking because Django has escaping mechanisms as well and could be re-escaping the antislashes when serving the json to the client, depending on how you put it. Did you check whether the double antislashes are present in the database or not?

Comment: @spectras I think you are onto something! I realized that the output of `json.dumps` has double slashes, but the string printed in HTML has only one. So JS is escaping it properly, and printing a literal (single) slash. Any idea why `json.dumps` outputs double slashes?

Comment: `json.dumps` does not "output double slashes". That's what double encoding looks like (i.e. you encode JSON as JSON a second time). You say you store JSON at the database level. Decode the JSON before you pass it to `json.dumps`.

Comment: @Tomalak I actually have the exact same code as the one above on the server-side. I have a dict-that has strings with unicode characters, and I pass that to `json.dumps` which sends a string to the browser that has the double slashes. From what I understand, I need the server to send a string with single slashes, so that JS interprets those characters properly, correct? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to save the result of `json.dumps` to the database with the "single-slashed" version. I did it by calling `print` on the result of `json.dumps` and then copy-pasting that to the database.

Comment: If you were just visualizing it in the interpreter, remember to use print. Otherwise, the interpreter re-escapes strings. This is because it does not show the string itself, rather it presents you with something you can copy-paste into python to re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the json file in UTF8 instead of escaped charaters:

```
json.dumps(final_res,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

For example

```
print json.dumps({'name':u'l\u00a0m\u00fcdale'},ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
# {"name": "l müdale"}
```

Then in your client side AJAX code, set the encoding to 'utf8' :
[How to set encoding in .getJSON JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620/how-to-set-encoding-in-getjson-jquery)

```
$.ajax({ contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", ... })
```